# Fractional Knapsack java implementation

Tags: java, algorithm

So I get the whole idea of the fractional knapsack problem, which is to optimally fill your container with fractional amounts of the given items that you have.

However, I'm confused to how I can implement this algorithm into a java function? I need to solve it for my Coursera course. So if anyone can explain how to write this function I would really appreciate it. This is the question prompt:

> Task. The goal of this code problem is to implement an algorithm for the > fractional knapsack problem.
>   Input Format. The first line of the input contains the number n of items > and the capacity W of a knapsack.
>   The next n lines define the values and weights of the items. The i-th > line contain integers vi and wi —
>   the value and the weight of i-th item, respectively.
>   Constraints. 1 ≤ n ≤ 103

This is what I have so far (this includes starter code from which the course provided to me)

`

```
public class FractionalKnapsack {
  private static double getOptimalValue(int capacity, int[] values, int[] weights) {
        //filling array vallues with 0
        Arrays.fill(values,0);
        //total value is 0
        double value = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
            if(W==0){
                return 
            }
        }
        //write your code here
        //fit first the item with the maximal value per unit

        //while knapsack is not full
        //choose item with maxmimum v/wi
        //if item fits into knapsack, take all of it
        //else take so much to fill knapsack to end
        //return total value and amounts taken

        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int capacity = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] values = new int[n];
        int[] weights = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            values[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            weights[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Fractional Knapsack implies you can use Greedy Algorithm. You should fill with that item which has the highest `value/weight` ratio. Sort all your items in decreasing order of the above ratio and start filling the knapsack with items one by one until knapsack is full.

For the last item you are putting in knapsack, that can be either full or partial which will depend upon the space left for that last item in the knapsack.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's sad that ppl ask about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to code yourself with following steps:

1.Take a double array with ratio of value to weight.

2.Sort the ratio array along with the weight array.

3.Take product of weight and ratio one by one until the Knapsack gets filled up.